# Corona sdk + xmpp

Tags: lua, xmpp, coronasdk

Does anyone know if there is some XMPP library I could use in Corona SDK, to build Android and iOS apps? I thought about [verse](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/verse/home) library. But I am not sure if it is possible to use it in Corona SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verse is not pure Lua, and nor is Prosody (which is less impure), as they rely on LuaSocket and other extensions. Lua doesn't come with built-in network functionality. Corona does in fact include LuaSocket, so I'm guessing you can get Prosody to work with some effort, but it's not drop-in-and-go.

Comment: You need LuaSocket, LuaExpat, LuaSec and LuaFileSystem